# assert_called_with failing with empty error message

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to learn python's testing tools and have set up what I though would be a very simple use of `@patch()`.

I have made a very simple function that doesn't do anything (but also does not raise an error):

```
aULR = "https://example.com"

def getURL():
    with urllib.request.urlopen(aULR) as f:
        pass
```

I then patch `urlopen` and call my function with:

```
@patch('urllib.request.urlopen')
def test(MockClass1):
    getURL()
    assert MockClass1.assert_called_with('test')

test()
```

This fails as expected with the assertion error I was hoping for:

```
AssertionError: Expected call: urlopen('test')
Actual call: urlopen('https://example.com')
```

But when I pass the correct url in the test with:

```
@patch('urllib.request.urlopen')
def test(MockClass1):
    getURL()
    assert MockClass1.assert_called_with('https://example.com')

test()
```

I still get an error, but this time it is an unhelpful AssertionError with no message:

```
AssertionError:
```

I'm a little shaky on how I am supposed to be doing this, so I'm not sure what is going on here. Why is this test still failing and why am I getting an empty error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the initial `assert`, just write:

```
MockClass1.assert_called_with('https://example.com')
```

`assert_called_with` is returning something falsy, probably `None`, and `assert None` raises an `AssertionError`.